# I want to remove xml node from file where in xml user selects path?

Tags: c#, xml

That code does not work. It not remove path4 node how can I do it? Please help me. Thank you.

```
<WindowEntries>
<WindowEntry>
  <Name>tbwUnitOverview</Name>
  <View>TRN_UNIT</View>
  <LU>TrnUnit</LU>
  <DefaultWindowText> windowtext</DefaultWindowText>
  <Flags>0</Flags>
</WindowEntry>
<WindowEntry>
  <Name>tbwBrandOverView</Name>
  <View>TRN_BRAND</View>
  <LU>TrnBrand</LU>
  <DefaultWindowText />
  <Flags>0</Flags>
</WindowEntry>
<WindowEntry>
  <Name>tbwProductCategory</Name>
  <View>TRN_PROD_CATEGORY</View>
  <LU>TrnProdCategory</LU>
  <DefaultWindowText />
  <Flags>0</Flags>
</WindowEntry>
```

```
         XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("component.xml");
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            XmlNode currNode;
            string path4 = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString();

                currNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(path4);
                currNode.RemoveAll();



            doc.Save("component.xml");
```

Comment: that code does not work . it not remove path4 node how can i do it please help me. thank you.

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074621/how-do-i-replace-a-xml-node/7074676#7074676

Comment: Are your first understanding the code you have written? Have you debugged it?

Comment: yes now i try that way . but it not work.

Comment: If it didnt, then why are you duplicating threads?

Comment: i debugged it . when i click that button it generate some error.

Comment: You dont sound you have enough analyzed this code nor debugged it. Sorry mate. Please either read about XML and then debug this code.

Comment: What does the variable `path4` contain? What's the exact error message you get and on which line of the code?

Comment: this XML file show as a treeview. when user want to remove entry he should  select that entry from treeview. path4 is user selected place in treeview.it may be  <WindowEntry> when user select that entry i have to design button to remove all elements in that <WindowEntry> entry.  errorr is 'Component\WindowEntries\kkkkkkkkkkk' has an invalid token.      "'Component\WindowEntries\kkkkkkkkkkk" is user selected path (path4) in treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are removing all child nodes and attributes of the node you are selecting from the document and not the actual node itsself.

See: [XmlNode.RemoveAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removeall.aspx)

If you want to remove the actual node you will need to access the parent node ([XmlNode.ParentNode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode.aspx)) and then call the RemoveChild method ([XmlNode.RemoveChild Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild.aspx)) passing in the node you wish to remove like so:

```
string path4 = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString();
XmlNode nodeToRemove = doc.SelectSingleNode(path4);
XmlNode parentNode = nodeToRemove.ParentNode;
parentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you provide me with details of the exception? The exception is likely to be caused by the XPath value held in the path4 variable. If this path is incorrect the nodeToRemove (above) will be null and will cause an exception on subsequent method/property calls.

Comment: it is a run time error when i click button it say xpathException was unhandle and  'Component\WindowEntries\WindowEntry' has an invalid token.

Comment: As I thought it looks like your XPath is incorrect in some way. You will need to debug your code to determine the value of the path4 variable so you can determine what is wrong.